# How to execute a nested if statement only when all the iterations of the parent loop are true?

Tags: c++

I am attempting [problem 5](https://projecteuler.net/problem=5) of Project Euler. I am required to find the smallest integer divisible by first 20 natural numbers.

My thought is to initialise the `smallest` variable to 2520(as it is given in the question) and start the loop at 11 and then divide `smallest` by numbers from 11 to 20. If it divisible by all the values of i, then the system should print `smallest`. Otherwise, it should increase `smallest` by 1. Below is my code so far.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int smallest = 2520;
    for(int i = 11; i<=20; i++){
        if(smallest%i==0){
            cout<<smallest;  //I want this statement to be executed only when the if statement is true for all values of i.
            break;
        } else {
                smallest++; //In case the if statement is false for any value of i, then do this.
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Running my code gives me the answer: 2522

The correct answer is: 232792560

Currently, if even a single value from 11 to 20 can divide `smallest`, then it breaks the loop and prints it, but I want it to print only when all the values from 11 to 20 can divide it.

Comment: You only find the *first* number where `smallest % i` equals zero. You need to check *all* values of `i`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude How do I check for all the values of `i`?

Comment: A naive solution would be to have two loops, one nested inside the other. The outer loop for `smallest` and the inner for `i`. If inside the inner loop you have `smallest % i != 0` then you continue the outer loop.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I do not understand. Can you please illustrate with code? My inner loop has `smallest % i !=0`, and suppose if that condition is false, what do I do next? Do I break the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Currently, if even a single value from 11 to 20 can divide smallest, then it breaks the loop and prints it, but I want it to print only when all the values from 11 to 20 can divide it.

Making sub-function might help:

```
bool is_divisible_by_any_of_range_11_to_20(int n)
{
    for (int i = 11; i <= 20; ++i) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false; // Outside of the loop
}
```

then your code would be:

```
int smallest = 2520;
while (is_divisible_by_any_of_range_11_to_20(smallest)) {
    ++smallest;
}
```

> My thought is to initialise the smallest variable to 2520(as it is given in the question) and start the loop at 11 and then divide smallest by numbers from 11 to 20

The logic is wrong even if it works in that case as each number from 1-10 has at least one multiple in 11-20:

reduce the problem to find smallest number for 1-11 and apply your logic:

Next number divisible by 11 from 2520 is 2530 (230 * 11) which is not divisible by 3.

The brute force algorithm would require to check if it is also divisible by each numbers from 1-10 (so by 2520).

There are several way to improve your algorithm, increase by one is not the efficient way.

You might to compute the Least Common Multiple (lcm) of 2520 and 11 (as 11 is prime, it is 11 * 2520 = 27720).

Your code should be so something like:

```
int res = 1;
for (int i = 1; i != 21; ++i) {
    res = std::lcm(res, i);
}
```

or,

```
int res = 2520;
for (int i = 11; i != 21; ++i) {
    res = std::lcm(res, i);
}
```

Comment: Your answer is really thorough, but tell me, will there be a significant difference if I use `smallest++` instead of `++smallest`?

Comment: @AdityaPrakash On a line, by itself? No. In some situations `x++` will be slower than `++x` (depending on the type of `x` and the context of the increment statement). But, if `x` is an int or other primitive type and the increment is on a line of its own, then there is no difference at all.

Answer (score 1):

#1 I have to point this out. I would personally strongly recommend not using the `using namespace std`, since it defeats the purpose of having namespaces(of course a bit overkill in this case)

#2 For good practice, you should test all integers from 1 to 20, as being divisible by the integers 11 to 20 do not necessarily mean that they are divisible by 1 to 10 (but in this case they are).

#3 You can add some kind of counter such as `numDivisible` for the # of numbers that divide `smallest`, that you check, when it reaches 20, you break the loop. Otherwise, you reset it to 0 and increment `smallest`.

Another method: inside the `if` branch of the conditional, you can add:

```
if(i==20) {
    //Whatever else you need to do
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but is there any other way apart from using `numDivisible`? I would like to keep the number of variables to a minimum.

Comment: You can take a similar approach to @Suraj by checking `if(i==20){break;}` when in the `if(smallest%i==0)` branch.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have already gotten help with your code, I will instead try to poke at your algorithm.

Try to think back to your math classes and remember prime decomposition (10 = 2*5, 12 = 2*2*3, etc.). Then recall that a number is divisible by a number if and only if it is divisible by *all* the primes it decomposes into (at their highest power - a number is divisible by 12 if it is divisible by 2^2 and 3).

What does that mean in this context? Instead of looping through ~232000000 numbers, try to prime decompose 1-20 and record the max power you see every prime at. Then multiply all those together to get your answer.

Example. 1-10 decomposes like this:

```
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   2^2
5   5
6   2*3
7   7
8   2^3
9   3^2
10  2*5
```

As you can see, the highest powers here are:

```
2^3
3^2
5
7
```

And if we multiply those, then: `2^3 * 3^2 * 5 * 7 = 2520` which is the example answer you got in the problem.

Decompose the next 10 numbers too and we arrive at: `2^4 * 3^2 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19 = 232,792,560`.

And going for the next 10 again gives us: `2^4 * 3^3 * 5^2 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19 * 23 * 29 = 2,329,089,562,800` - looping that high might take a while.

Anyway, it doesn't have a lot to do with your code, but it might be a nice challenge to figure out how to code this prime decomposition solution, and I figured that if you are doing Project Euler problems you might appreciate seeing an alternative approach. :)

Comment: This was awesome! I guess coding really wasn't required after all. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int smallest = 2520;
    while(true){
        int i;
        for(i = 11 ; i<=20 ; i++)
            if(smallest%i != 0) break;
        if(i == 21){
            cout<<smallest;
            break;
        }
        smallest ++ ;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Does this solve your problem ??

Comment: Please do not ask for upvotes as respectable posts will naturally get upvoted.

Comment: Here is a diagram of for loop execution: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_for_loop.htm
Therefore, `i` will never equal 21

Comment: @mathmaniac88 , the execution followed by for loop is 
1 -> Initialization 2 -> Condition Checking 3-> body 4 -> Increment 5 -> repeat 2-4
So `i` will equal to 21 after the increment which will result in condition failure

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like given below.
If any number from 11 to 20 does not divide the smallest, increase smallest variable and set the counter back ( I set it to 10 as the termination condition of for loop will increase it to 11 ). The counter reaches 20 only if all previous counters divides it. So if 20 also divides it, print it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int smallest = 2520;
    for(int i = 11; i<=20; i++){
        if(i==20 && smallest%20==0){
            cout<<smallest;  //I want this statement to be executed only when the if statement is true for all values of i.
            break;
        } else if(smallest%20==0){
            continue; 
        } else {
                i=10;
                smallest++; //In case the if statement is false for any value of i, then do this.
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: By doing this, you omit the portion where `i` is not equal to 20, and checking if `smallest%i == 0`. In addition, in the `else` branch, you set `i=10`, which would cause an infinite loop.

Comment: Yes. Edited. Thanks.